# Numpy find the diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the corresponding eigenvalues

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a 2x2 matrix

[image]

And I want to find the diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the corresponding eigenvalues Λii = λi for i=1,2 using numpy

How would I do that?

Comment: That's a basic math question. What are the EVs of a 2 by 2 matrix?

Comment: `numpy.linalg.eig` family of functions

Comment: In this case, @MYousefi, both slower and more complicated than doing it by hand.

Comment: So, I should find the eigenvectors of the 2x2 matrix? How does that relate back to the question?

Comment: It's literally your assignment to put them in the diagonal of a matrix

Comment: Alright, so If I am understanding correctly I must get the eigvenvectors and them somehow put them in the diagonal of the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

First calculate eigenvalues using numpy.linalg.eigvals and create a matrix

**Eigen1 0**

**0 Eigen2**